# GWT formpanel does not call onSubmitComplete

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

GWT: I can call the servlet in browser. When I call it by formpanel, it can call onSubmit. But it does not call onSubmitComplete. It wil also popup a new window, the uri is my servlet.

```
String URL= GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"getType";
         FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();  
         formPanel.setAction(URL); 
         formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_URLENCODED);  
         formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_GET); 

     formPanel.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(event.getSource());
        }

     });
     formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {  
            public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) { 
                System.out.println("in");
                System.out.println(event.getResults());  
            }  
        });  
     formPanel.submit();

GWT.xml
 <servlet class="msp2.server.getType" path="/getType" />  


web.xml
    <servlet >
<servlet-name>getType</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>msp2.server.getType</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>getType</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/msp2_app/getType</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I was just having the same problem and none of these answers were the solution. After calling `FormPanel.submit()`, the response would open in a new tab and `onSubmitComplete()` would not be called.

The solution ended up being that my `FormPanel` was not added to my dialog which called `submit()`. Since the form consists entirely of `Hidden` fields, whose values are set depending on the button on the page that is pressed, my `FormPanel` doesn't actually contain any form widgets with user selectable values, so I didn't have the need to add it to the window anywhere.

This is what was causing the response to open in a new window and `onSubmitComplete()` not being called. I added it to the panel for my `DialogBox` and after that it worked as it should.

Answer (score 2):

From [the javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#FormPanel%28%29):

> The back-end server is expected to respond with a content-type of 'text/html', meaning that the text returned will be treated as HTML. If any other content-type is specified by the server, then the result HTML sent in the onFormSubmit event will be unpredictable across browsers, and the onSubmitComplete event may not fire at all.

Given you say that the response opens in another window, and you didn't set a specific *target* to your `FormPanel`, it's probably the case that your server doesn't do `response.setContentType("text/html")` (or similar with a `;charset=` parameter)

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled through

> It wil also popup a new window

All the answers I've found were about adding form widget to panel or adding the FormPanel itself instead of widget, making the action link absolute and other stuff that didn't gelp. The solution that REALLY WORKED for me after an hour of tries was **reading javadoc**

```
  public FormPanel(String target) {...}
```

> @param target the name of the <iframe> to receive the results of the
>               submission, or `null` to specify that the current page
>              be replaced

Simply pass "_self" to FormPanel constructor

```
FormPanel form = new FormPanel("_self");
```

Or set it later via .setTarget(...) method. Whoa - It doesn't open a popup(which surely will be blocked by Chrome) Also creating a form in the method and submiting it without even appending to the DOM works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

onSubmitComplete will be called if the form submission is successfully completed. Make sure that there is no error in form submission.

Post the code you are trying. It will help others to figure out the problem.

You can also try the example of using FormPanel provided [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html)

Comment: I have post the code. I can call the servlet by type it in browser. But I submit the form. On submit function will work. The submission is not completed.

Comment: As of GWT 1.6, you don't need to configure your servlet in gwt.xml. Make sure that the servlet is getting invoked and there are no exceptions in the servlet

Comment: In the servlet, I just response a simple digit and this servlet could be visited by type the url. So it seems that the servlet works.

Comment: What I meant was, when you submit the form in GWT, make sure that the servlet is getting invoked.

Comment: How to chech my servlet is getting invoked? When I type a wrong servlet, it shows HTTP 404. But for the right servlet, it shows nothing.

Comment: Keep log messages in the servlet. You will know when it is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue it turns out to be I did not set the action URL of the FormPanel.

```
final FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
formPanel.setAction("/test");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the iframes, which are used within the GWT app. There are often cross domain calls within Javascript during file uploads, which are not allowed. During development of the application, you open the Development Mode i.e. on port 9999, so your browser uses http://127.0.0.1:9999/YourApp.html. The servlet, which should handle the uploaded file runs on another machine or on the same machine but on another port (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:6544/servlet/upload). Both cases run into the Javascript security problem, because the domain includes the port number.

But you can install an Apache on your development machine and use mod_proxy to move both parts of your application into one domain. Set the -bindAddress to localhost and use a static port (i.e. 9999) for your GWT app. Also start the servlet on localhost with a static port (i.e. 6544). Then you can add

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyTimeout 3600

<Location /gui>
  Allow from All
  ProxyPass          http://localhost:9999
  ProxyPassReverse   http://localhost:9999
</Location>

<Location /api>
  Allow from All
  ProxyPass          http://localhost:6544/servlet
  ProxyPassReverse   http://localhost:6544/servlet
</Location>
```

to your Apache configuration. Now it is possible to start the GWT app with "http://localhost/gui/YourApp.html" and refer to "/api/upload" (relative Url) within FormPanel.setAction(). Now both domains (GWT app and upload-servlet) are within the same domain (http://localhost) and you will get the SubmitCompleteEvent.getResults(). Within the servlet you have to set the HTTP-response header "Content-Type" to "text/html" too.